# (Docker) RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ Sender, Receiver and Management running on Docker which is shown below.

[image]

All works perfectly well when I run Receiver and Sender on Local machine. But when I run it on Docker it gives me an error shown below.

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
```

[image]

Below is how I connect to the RabbitMQ.

Is there anything wrong on the setup or anything I need to change on how I connect to RabbitMQ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

when your application runs on a container, you should use a different host name for your rabbitMQ factory
for you web app localhost means your container environment, but your rabbit runs on another container

it would be better to set the host name from within the appsettings.json file and extract it from there in runtime,
but for now, test it with the actual hostname for rabbit container

in your case: `ecomm-rabbit`

and try to use this factory instead of building a url:

```
 var factory = new ConnectionFactory
                {
                    HostName = _hostname, // "ecomm-rabbit"
                    UserName = _username,
                    Password = _password
                };
                _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
```

also, if you are using a docker compose and you set it like this:

```
  rabbitmq: <-----
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
#    environment:
#      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user
#      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=password
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
```

the name of the service is translated to the hostname